# preserve \n when converting from byte[] to string

Tags: java, android, string, arrays

I have byte arrays and I wish to convert them to a string until a \n is received, then I want to make a new string. Something like:

```
if (dataReceived.charAt(i) != '\n') {
    parseCommand = parseCommand + dataReceived.charAt(i);

} else if (dataReceived.charAt(i) == '\n') {
    parseCommand = "";
}
```

But when i convert to a string from byte[] there are no \n's to test the string for. How can I preserve them? What is the best way to do this?

Is it better to buffer the incoming byte arrays/chunks until I have a complete line (eg when a newline is received) and then create the String out of these byte arrays, or can I maintain them in a string?

Comment: Can you paste the code you're using to convert your byte[] to a String?

Comment: I just have dataReceived = new String(data, "UTF-8"); Easily changed if there is a preferable way.

Comment: did you try looking for `\r\n`?

Comment: Just \n so far, I thought if there is \r\n it would find it if I search for \n?

Comment: but your current code will ignore `\r`

Comment: I tried looking for \r also now, but it doesn't find it either.

Comment: Looked in a simple way dataReceived.charAt(i) == '\n' || dataReceived.charAt(i) == '\r'

Comment: how did you find it. paste your new code

Comment: if (dataReceived.charAt(i) == '\n' || dataReceived.charAt(i) == '\r') seems to find some new lines now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
char c = dataReceived.charAt(i);

if (c != '\n' && c != '\r')
    parseCommand = parseCommand + c;
else
    parseCommand = "";
```

Comment: Shouldn't that `||` be `&&` in the if - statement? As it stands now it will not detect `c == '\r'`.

Comment: This is good yes, thanks. My issue was not the code itself it seems but rather every now and again characters are being skipped. This appears to be random. For instance sometimes it is the \n that disappears and sometimes normal characters. "IP address" could be shown as "IP adess" for instance

Comment: This doesn't append the `\n` either.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

```
String data = ...;
Scanner s = new Scanner(data);
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
     String next = s.nextLine();
     // do something with next
}
```

Comment: This gets a whole line, and says the next byte received is a newline, even if there was no newline character. So if I receive testing\n as two byte arrays, "test" and "ing\n" that will count as 2 lines.

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about.

Comment: This method generates false newlines due to me receiving byte arrays as chunks. So I might receive one \n every 5 byte arrays but this would count that as 5 lines instead of one.